# Can I specify custom lifecycle methods in mvn

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I work with Node Package Manager (npm) on a daily basis and I wanted to know if it was possible to specify custom lifecycle methods in mvn similar to npm. For instance I can specify npm start to do any set of commands I'd like. Similarly I want to configure `mvn start` to run 
`mvn spring-boot:run -D"spring-boot.run.profiles=local`

Is it possble to acieve this. Otherwise I was thinking of making an alias for the same in bash

Comment: Simple answer to this: No you can not define custom life cycle states. Nor you need to ... npm there is a frontend-maven-plugin which is bound into the usual Maven lifecycle very well...So I don't understand the need for this request?

Comment: @khmarbaise My need is quite simple I don't want to run `mvn spring-boot:run -D"spring-boot.run.profiles=local` every time i want to run my project. If I could configure maven to do the same thing when I do something like `mvn start` or `mvn local` That would be awesome.

Comment: Shell script is the easiest solution or you use an IDE which supports that?

Comment: I have a shell script set up for this, but I wanted to know If I could specify I custom lifecycle in Maven similar to npm scripts

Answer (score 0):

Maven supports lifecycle customization, similar to Node Package Manager, but with a directly contrasting viewpoint with respect to scripting. So you won't find a direct equivalent to `npm-scripts`, with a `start` entry and a default value set to call `node` and pass a reference to a `server.js` script (just a warning about that key dissimilarity).

But Maven does provide alternative toolsets that have the same fundamental behavior and intent:

Similar to npm, everything in Maven is based on a central Build Lifecycle[<sup>intro</sup>](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), a clearly defined ordered set of `phase` elements (examples: `process-resources`, `compile`, `test`, `package`), each representing a discrete step in the core build lifecycle[<sup>ref</sup>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-core/lifecycles.html).

In addition, each `phase` is associated with one (or more) Maven `Plugin` component(s)[<sup>plugins</sup>](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html) that allow build process customization (examples: `clean`, `compiler`, `resources`, `jar`, `ear`, `checkstyle`, `javadoc`) including some that support: deployment, configuration, start (much like npm start), and stop of runtime containers, such as `cargo` (for J2EE containers) or `Apache Tomcat` (the most widely used webapp container). At its heart, Maven is essentially a plugin execution framework, all work is performed by plugins, custom lifecycle activity is based upon plugin configuration, and defined within the plugin `build` configuration or within the plugin `reporting` configuration[<sup>plugin-config</sup>](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html).